# How to display an image from my database, in my fancybox gallery?

Tags: php, image, mysqli, upload, fancybox

I have already made an image gallery for a client, and now he want to have the opportunity to upload pictures to the gallery. So I of course have already made a login system, which works just fine. I have made a quick upload form, which is kind of working - I can only upload one file, but I will fix that later. (You are welcome to help with this as well) 
My problem now is to get the image inside my gallery that I made with fancybox. how?

My gallery looks like this:

```
<div id="facader">
  <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" title="Facader" href="images/facade1.jpg"><img src="images/facade.jpg" alt=""/></a>

    <div class="hidden">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" title="Facader" href="images/facade2.jpg"><img src="images/facade2.jpg" width="221" height="166" alt=""/></a>

        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" title="Facader" href="images/facade3.jpg"><img src="images/facade3jpg"  alt="" width="220" height="220"/></a>

        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" title="Facader" href="images/facade4.jpg"><img src="images/facade4.jpg"  alt="" width="225" height="127"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

(This is just one of six categories)

My upload form looks like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File:
<input type="file" name="image"><input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php

//connect to database
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_database = "addina";

$db =  mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_database) or die("Error - cant connect or find db");


//file
print_r($_FILES); 
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if (!isset($file))
    echo "Please select an image";
else 
{
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if ($image_size==FALSE)
        echo "That's not an image.";
        else {
            if (!$insert = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO image VALUES ('$image_name','$image')")) 
            echo "Problem uploading the image.";
            else 
            {
                $lastid = mysqli_insert_id();
                echo "Image uploaded.<p />Your image:<p />IMAGE";
                        }
        }

}

?>
```

And my databse looks like this:

```
id int(11) unique null no AUTO_INCREMENT

name var(200) null no

images blob null no
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You have managed to upload images in folder right ? And you want is to display those image inside fancy box gallery, Right ?

Comment: It's Almost A Mystery For Me. *Why Few People Go In `<input type='hidden'>` Mode After Posting A Question?*. Really..

Comment: @NanaPartykar What do you mean?

Comment: @BikashP yes, that is what I want